# How to know if an android device is turned off from the server?

Tags: android, node.js

Can I ping the android device from the server to know if it is turned off?
I think there is no way to ping the server before the android device turns off. Particularly I will be doing this in node js

Thanks if you can guide me to the right path. Thanks!!

Comment: Why not implement heartbeat pings from your app?

Comment: whenever device is turned off you can log and you can get info at that time or later what exactly you want get when device was turned off or something else?

Comment: heartbeat pings? needs to have an internet connection. But nice suggestion. :)

Comment: if you need permanent connection eg via service. just send an "connection canceled" on service stop.

Comment: Use a Service on your Android app, call a "devicePresent" function in the onStartCommand() of the Service, then call a "deviceNotPresent" function in the onDestroy() method of your Service. Since Android could destroy the Service at any given time, use a Service that auto-restart. Also, take the devicePresent/NotPresent as a weak indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a persistent connection using a Faye server. That way, you will get to know when your device switches off. As a fallback, use an sms confirmation, just in case the network is not down.

Node.js example here.  https://github.com/faye/faye